# Is it statistically sound to use r mice to predict values instead of classic lm

Tags: r, predictive-models, mice

I have access to a population of around 5 million people. I also have access to multiple social and demographic variables (age, gender, level of education...). I randomly sampled 10,000 people from that population. I randomly divided this sample in 2 equal groups of 5,000 people. I sent a survey to one of those 2 groups and some people answered. I wanted to check if some answers to my survey would be correlated with real-life outcomes after a couple of months.

Unfortunately, being surveyed can change later behaviors. This is why I only sent the survey to 1 group, because I now want want to predict the answers of the 5,000 people who did not receive the survey and see if the correlation still holds when not being surveyed (i.e. "free" of any "being surveyed effect").

I would normally use a linear regression model with `lm(y ~ age + sexe + gender + etc...)` and then use `predict(lm, ...)`.

However, would it be statistically sound to use predictive mean matching for instance with r mice ? Since mice imputes multiple datasets and accounts for that multiple imputation process in further analyses, I though it could be better than runing lm in a single dataframe.

I found a lot of questions about using predict with mice object, but never about using mice to directly predict data. Is there anything wrong with it ?

Thanks all

**EDIT :**
I've used words interchangeably and shouldn't have. I replaced *impute* with *predict*, defining prediction as "filling in missing Y". I also answered Adam's questions and gave more details.

Comment: You are using the words "estimate" and "predict" exchangeably when they're not exchangeable. i.e. "estimate the answer of..." and then "...account for predictive errors." The calculation/application of errors underscores the difference. Can you rewrite the question to focus on exactly what you're trying to estimate?

Comment: You say you "randomized" the "population" of 10,000 people. Can you confirm a. that there are really only 10,000 people in existence - or do you mean to say 10,000 was the sample which was subsequently randomized into the survey and no-survey arms. And how did you sample, and how did you randomized?

Comment: You then say the goal of this exercise is to obtain matched pairs within survey and no-survey groups. If this is the case, what kind of baseline variables are supplied as an input? If the no-survey group has absolutely no predictive variables, no algorithmic pairing can perform any better than just random matching - which is useless.

Comment: Thanks @AdamO I edited my question to give more details

Answer (score 0):

It's 'wrong'.

Lm will predict the values and you have an rmse, si you can even generate new y (as predicted y + normal(0,rmse)

I can't remember predictive mean matching, but essentially it's using a different underlying model (knn?), so if you want to do that, you can just do it directly (instead of using lm)

Mice is useful if you have missing data in your independent (and dependent) variables, scattered about. That is not athe case here, you have a straightforward prediction problem

Comment: I think this is a half-baked answer - at its core this *is* a missing data problem; in another universe you might have administered the survey to which they would have supplied answers (a frequentist). 1/

Comment: And you haven't said much about why MICE *wouldn't* be useful here. OP's question might be whether MICE provides a more robust predictive error model for the response than the LM model - it's described as an "approximate Bayesian Bootstrap", so does that mean that even with a normal prior, the posterior for the missing response can mix a likelihood that shows skewness or kurtosis. Of course, they didn't ask that, but to say it's "wrong" requires more comment. 2/2